# How Create Whatsapp Auto reply Button using VB 2019 Selenium Chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

hello frnds and developer

if want create whatsapp automation with bot using Selenium Chrome in vb 2019

but till now we cant create button on whatsapp message for auto reply , i find some code in nodejs ,

but its not working or new update code .js or vb 2019 using Selenium Chrome

pls reply me if any good developer of vb 2019 using Selenium Chrome

live example :

https://github.com/adiwajshing/Baileys

[image: Button Type 1 image]

[image: Button Type 2 image]

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question, show us the code for example.  Might also pay to check your question tags so you get the appropriate answers.  What's the linked repo about?  You've specific said you want to use Selenium then linked a repo that in the very first line says it doesn't use Selenium.  Explain to us exactly what you're doing and how what you've done isn't working

Comment: any other option , send a list message using Selenium Chrome in vb 2019

Comment: *i find some code in nodejs... but its not working* Then please [edit] your code to include a [mcve] reproducing your problem within the question itself.  From [ask]: *if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem... If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but **also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Comment: As it is, absent a [mcve], your question is likely to get closed as lacking details.  For guidance on how to write a question that is likely to get an answer here, see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ or, in short form, https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you or not but, you can install Whatsapp business and setup auto reply there in the settings

Comment: i want Selenium Chrome code using VB 2019